Does the order matter when submitting a increase compute budget instruction
Suppose I have an instruction that will use up all of the available 200K CU.
Will the order i.e. placing the increase compute units either at the beginning of the transaction or at the end matter?
Looking at the program runtime code, there doesn't seem to be priorities in the execution of transactions.

It does not. If you check the compute budget calculation code here you can see it iterates through all instructions to find the ones that set the CU Limit and CU Price.
